# How to extract a single JSON property in Spring Boot Application?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, openfeign

I am feeling kind of lost since I already struggled with some dependencies in my pom.xml, but what I am trying to do is to extract a single property from a JSON in my Spring Boot Application.

I have a FilmServiceClient, declared as FeignClient which fetches some data from IMDb, which looks as following:

```
{
    "Title": "Kingsman: The Secret Service",
    "Year": "2014",
    "Rated": "R",
     [...]
    "Metascore": "60",
    "imdbRating": "7.7",
    "imdbVotes": "597,264",
     [...]
}
```

In my FilmService, I would like to implement a getRating method which extracts the `imdbRating` from the JSON as double attribute, which I eventually want to add to the Film entity in my DB.

I am grateful for every advise as well as the necessary dependencies and imports, thank you in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you want to familiarize yourself with Jackson.  It's easy/painless: honest.  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson/, https://www.baeldung.com/jackson, https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to paulsm4, I studied the information from baeldung.com/jackson and could extract the necessary data perfectly :)

If interested, this is how my code looks like now:

```
    protected String getRating(String title) throws Exception{
        String rating;
        String film = fsc.getFilmInfo(title);
        try{
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(film);
            JsonNode node = tree.get("imdbRating");
            rating = node.textValue();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            rating = "0.0";
        }
        return rating;
    }
```

As result, it returns "7.7" as String as stated in the JSON above.

Thanks and have a good night!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert json string to object as below. Then you can access properties of film object.

Here Film is POJO with same properties defined in json string

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
Film film = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Film.class);
```

Film POJO

```
public class Film {

    private String title;
    private double imdbRating;
    [...]
    // getters and setters


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
double imdbRating = objectMapper.readTree(json).findValue("imdbRating").asDouble();
System.out.println(imdbRating);
```

Output:

```
7.7
```

---

If you don't seem to have ObjectMapper, you can add the dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```